# Apache Ignite cluster node not loading all data from external DB

Tags: ignite

I am completely new to Apache Ignite and trying out some examples for evaluating IMDG capabilities of Ignite. I am using GridGain web console to create a simple project where I have imported a single table from my MSSQL external database. This is a large table with ~9 million records with over 100 columns. After downloading the project, compiling in VS Code, and deploying the packaged JAR file in ignite installation folder, I start the cluster (single node). So far so good, I can see the cluster and node in my GridGain web console. However, every time I try to load the cache, it only loads ~44K records which I am able to query (e.g. using DBeaver). I tried setting the dataRegion mem size to 12G. The machine has 32G RAM and over 70% is free. The cache does have Read-Through enabled and I understand that key-value access via API can read all data. However I am trying to run SQL on the cache to aggregate the data for my evaluation. Why does the node/cache not load all data from my external MSSQL DB? Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Node Log:

```
Metrics for local node (to disable set 'metricsLogFrequency' to 0)
    ^-- Node [id=a9347dd0, name=MyCluster, uptime=00:01:00.045]
    ^-- Cluster [hosts=1, CPUs=4, servers=1, clients=0, topVer=1, minorTopVer=0]
    ^-- Network [addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 10.10.100.60, 127.0.0.1], discoPort=47500, commPort=47100]
    ^-- CPU [CPUs=4, curLoad=76.53%, avgLoad=11.27%, GC=0.1%]
    ^-- Heap [used=485MB, free=52.6%, comm=1024MB]
    ^-- Off-heap memory [used=10MB, free=99.92%, allocated=336MB]
    ^-- Page memory [pages=2586]
    ^--   sysMemPlc region [type=internal, persistence=false, lazyAlloc=false,
      ...  initCfg=40MB, maxCfg=100MB, usedRam=0MB, freeRam=99.21%, allocRam=40MB]
    ^--   default region [type=default, persistence=false, lazyAlloc=true,
      ...  initCfg=256MB, maxCfg=12288MB, usedRam=9MB, freeRam=99.92%, allocRam=256MB]
    ^--   TxLog region [type=internal, persistence=false, lazyAlloc=false,
      ...  initCfg=40MB, maxCfg=100MB, usedRam=0MB, freeRam=100%, allocRam=40MB]
    ^-- Outbound messages queue [size=0]
    ^-- Public thread pool [active=0, idle=0, qSize=0]
    ^-- System thread pool [active=0, idle=6, qSize=0]
[16:31:43,959][INFO][grid-timeout-worker-#22%MyCluster%][IgniteKernal%MyCluster] FreeList [name=default##FreeList, buckets=256, dataPages=2879, reusePages=0]
[16:32:44,021][INFO][grid-timeout-worker-#22%MyCluster%][IgniteKernal%MyCluster]
Metrics for local node (to disable set 'metricsLogFrequency' to 0)
    ^-- Node [id=a9347dd0, name=MyCluster, uptime=00:03:00.212]
    ^-- Cluster [hosts=1, CPUs=4, servers=1, clients=0, topVer=1, minorTopVer=0]
    ^-- Network [addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 10.10.100.60, 127.0.0.1], discoPort=47500, commPort=47100]
    ^-- CPU [CPUs=4, curLoad=56.37%, avgLoad=49.36%, GC=0.03%]
    ^-- Heap [used=197MB, free=80.74%, comm=1024MB]
    ^-- Off-heap memory [used=31MB, free=99.75%, allocated=336MB]
    ^-- Page memory [pages=8089]
    ^--   sysMemPlc region [type=internal, persistence=false, lazyAlloc=false,
      ...  initCfg=40MB, maxCfg=100MB, usedRam=0MB, freeRam=99.21%, allocRam=40MB]
    ^--   default region [type=default, persistence=false, lazyAlloc=true,
      ...  initCfg=256MB, maxCfg=12288MB, usedRam=30MB, freeRam=99.75%, allocRam=256MB]
    ^--   TxLog region [type=internal, persistence=false, lazyAlloc=false,
      ...  initCfg=40MB, maxCfg=100MB, usedRam=0MB, freeRam=100%, allocRam=40MB]
    ^-- Outbound messages queue [size=0]
    ^-- Public thread pool [active=0, idle=0, qSize=0]
    ^-- System thread pool [active=0, idle=7, qSize=0]
[16:32:44,144][INFO][grid-timeout-worker-#22%MyCluster%][IgniteKernal%MyCluster] FreeList [name=default##FreeList, buckets=256, dataPages=5466, reusePages=0]
[16:33:21,844][INFO][rest-#60%MyCluster%][CacheJdbcPojoStore] Finished load cache: DmdtxnCache
```

Comment: Do you have logs during the cache.loadCache()? It would be great to see the generated configuration.

Comment: Hi Vladimir, I have added the log to my issue description from the Node window when executing Load Cache in my web console browser UI. Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Anything special about these records? Any exceptions in the log? Are you sure that you're wiring Ignite to your main database and not some testing trunk?